# Tension in cord is half harmonic mean (Interpretation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

> *Calculate the tension ($T$), in terms of $m$, $M$ and $g$ in a cord, where an object of mass $m$ overhangs a table via a cord attached to a mass $M$. Ignore friction, and assume the cord is massless, and inextensible.*

This is a common question on Newton's Laws of Motion, and can be calculated by solving a system of equations:
$$ma=mg-T,Ma=T\implies T=\left(\frac{mM}{m+M}\right)g$$

The $\frac{mM}{m+M}$ term is half the harmonic mean of $m$ and $M$.
What process causes the harmonic mean to occur here? For example, harmonic mean is used in averaging speed, or averaging cost.

If you calculate the same expression for an Atwood machine, you get the Harmonic mean.

Comment: Given that the factor of two is missing I think that term just happens to look something  like a (harmonic) mean with $\left( \frac 1 M +\frac 1 m \right)\,T = g$.

Comment: If you calculate the same expression for an Atwood machine, you get the Harmonic mean itself.

Comment: Sometimes algebra is just algebra, with no “interpretation”.

Answer (score 0):

assume the cord is massless, but  **extensible**, thus you obtain this system

[image]

the equations of motion are

$$ M\,\ddot x_M+T=0\quad,m\,\ddot x_m-T=m\,g$$

now instead of the coordinates $~x_M~,x_m~$ we what to use the center of mass coordinate $~x_c~$ and the relative coordinate $~r~$

where
$$x_c=\frac {M\,x_M+m\,x_m}{m+M}\quad, r=x_m-x_M$$

the equations of motion are now

$$\ddot r_c+\frac{m\,g}{m+M}=0\\
\ddot r+g-\frac{m+M}{m\,M}\,T=0$$

your case is the cord   inextensible

$$\ddot r=0\quad\Rightarrow
T=\frac{m\,M}{m+M}\,g$$

thus the result that you obtained is " some think to do of the  with the center of mass motion"  not with the  harmonic mean.

Comment: This generalizes but does not really explain why the harmonic mean comes up. That is my main question,

Comment: I don't think  that the result of the tension is some think to do with  he harmonic mean